# strip_tags() on MySQLi Query and PHP Function

Tags: php, mysql, string, function, mysqli

I'm trying hard to learn how to create functions, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Could someone explain it to me please?

I'm not using strip_tags(), why it's getting me this error?

I don't need it to return, I just to need to update database if
`$xp is bigger than $row['basenumber']`

Thank you!

```
$xp = $row['userxp'];
$lvl = $row['userlevel'];

contXP($xp, $lvl);
```

function:

```
function contXP ($xp, $lvl) {

    $query = "SELECT 
              number, basenumber 
              FROM levels
              WHERE number = '$lvl'";

    $result = $conn ->query($query);    
        if (!$result) die ($conn->error);

    $rows = $result->num_rows; 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array (MYSQLI_ASSOC));     

    if ($xp >= $row['basenumber']) 
      {
          // up level
          $level = "UPDATE users
                    SET userlevel = userlevel + 1
                    WHERE idusers = '$iduser';";    

          $re_level = $conn ->query($level);    
          if (!$re_level) die ($conn->error);

          $re_rows = $re_level->num_rows; 
          $re_row = $re_level->fetch_array (MYSQLI_ASSOC);  

          $re_level->close(); //close query   

      }     

    $result->close(); //close query


}
```

result:

```
Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in on line 32
```

Comment: `strip_tags()` isn't in your question's code. it's somewhere though, maybe in an included file; who knows.

Comment: @Bibiana `$conn` isn't defined inside the `contXP` function. I'm not sure what are you running here? but definitely not the code you posted.

Comment: True, I've forget to define global (I know it's not good, but I didn't learn yet how to make class). What I'm trying is to get $xp and $lvl vars from one query, and send them to a function, and work with them on that function. Can I do that?

Comment: I've lost 3 points cause I asked a question?!! You could have just sayied that this code don't show this error. How could I know this error is from another code if my function didn't show any error but still didn't works?! I think I'll ask questions in another place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strilp_tags() is definitely somewhere in your code to throw the error. Try posting all the codes involved so we can find out where your problem is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for heads up. Code is too long. I'll check another place.